# Angular Bootstrap Typeahead Service issue

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

Hello I'm trying to build a `Bootstrap Typeahead` in angular where I integrate a service for JSON data for the autocomplete.

Here is my typeahead code in my component -

```
export class NgbdTypeaheadBasic {
public model: any;
searchList: Search[];
constructor(private searchservice: SearchService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.searchList = this.searchservice.getSearch();
}

search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
  text$.pipe(
    debounceTime(200),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    map(term => term.length < 2 ? []
      : searchList.filter(v => v.searchitem.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10))
  );

 }
```

Here is my input box-

```
<input type="search" [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search">
```

Here is my service code -

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Search } from '../data/search';
import { SEARCH } from '../data/searchdata';

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {

  constructor() { }

  getSearch(): Search[]{
    return SEARCH;
  }
}
```

Here is my example data -

search.ts

```
export class Search{
 id: number;
 searchitem: string;
 url: string;
}
```

searchdata.ts -

```
    import { Search } from './search';

export const SEARCH: Search[] = [
    {
        id:1,
        searchitem: 'jeans',
        url: 'https://www.google.co.in',
    },
    {
        id:2,
        searchitem: 'Shirts',
        url: 'https://www.facebook.com',
    }
];
```

I am getting an error as -

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'searchList'.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use **`this.searchList`**

**`this.searchList.filter(v => v.searchitem.toLowerCase()`**